# How to extract parameter from icalendar event in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, icalendar

I'm fairly new to Ruby and am working on a small project. I'd like to print out some details from an iCalendar (*.ics file) event. To handle the ics-File I use the [icalendar gem](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar).

So far, I've managed to extract the correct event but I also need to print out the attendee. My problem: The ATTENDEE field is using several parameters. Here is an example:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150527T074021Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150525
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150530
SUMMARY:OnCall Duty
UID:1234
DESCRIPTION:
CREATED:20150512T063102Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20150512T063102Z
ATTENDEE;X-MYUSER-KEY=dfdfdf;CN=Jon 
 Doe;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL:mailto:Jon.Doe@acme.com
SEQUENCE:1
X-CONFLUENCE-SUBCALENDAR-TYPE:other
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
require 'icalendar'
require 'active_support/all'
require 'open-uri'

ics_file  = File.open("ops.ics")
cal = Icalendar.parse(ics_file).first
events = cal.events

now = DateTime.now
currentOnDuty = events.select{ |e| e.summary == "OnCall Duty" && e.dtstart.to_time >= now.beginning_of_week && e.dtend.to_time <= now.end_of_week }

puts "User: #{currentOnDuty.first.attendee}"
```

which creates the following output:

```
[#<URI::MailTo Jon.Doe@acme.com>]
```

What I rather need is the "CN" parameter for ATTENDEE. So I would like to get the output:

```
User: Jon Doe
```

The docs have only a few examples for creating an event with parameters but so far I could not figure out how to extract a certain parameter.

Any hints on how to extract "CN"-parameter from the ATTENDEE field?

---

Solution:

> currentOnDuty.first.attendee.ical_params[:cn].first

Comment: what you get in `currentOnDuty` object?

Comment: currentOnDuty is an array of Icalendar::Event objects. Since I only need one event i use currentOnDuty.first.

Comment: Would you mind to try `puts currentOnDuty.first.attendee.inspect` and share an output, please. Plus, try `puts currentOnDuty.first.attendee.cn`.

Comment: attendee.inspect prints out `[#<URI::MailTo mailto:Jon.Doe@acme.com>]` and attendee.cn gives me an `undefined method 'cn'`

Comment: Two more suggestions: print out `...attendee.class` and try `...attendee['cn']`, `...attendee['CN']` and `...attendee[:cn]`.

Comment: `attendee.class` gives me `Array`. The other variantes print out `'[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Icalendar` wraps `ical` with [values](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/master/lib/icalendar/value.rb), so that:

```
▶ cal.first.events.first.attendee.first.class
#⇒ Icalendar::Values::CalAddress < Icalendar::Values::Uri
```

This class has `ical_params` attribute exposed:

```
▶ cal.first.events.first.attendee.first.ical_params[:cn]
#⇒ [ [0] "John Doe" ]
```

So (you’d like probably to check the presence of this attribute):

```
▶ cal.first.events.first.attendee.first.ical_params[:cn].first
#⇒ "John Doe"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That was the final hint! Thanks a lot.